# Swift: Complex JSON Model data not properly showing in UITableView

Tags: ios, json, swift, uitableview, decodable

I have a complex JSON (nested values) in it, I properly implemented and data values are in model. But for some unknown reasons its not printing complete data only showing me first `12 values` and actually it has `71 data values`.
I know I am doing something wrong in adjusting `indexPath` because of complex data. My model and json are complex(nested) and iterations one.

1. I need to show tableView data which has specific only like - action type `actionType": 101` and `title` as section in picklist(check json) and `textField` values in tableView list.
2. So how can I properly set `AppData?.items?[indexPath.row]` this for section and for row.

> Note: I only need one action type from JSON which is 101 and Title as a tableView Section and textField as list values and these both in pickList. I attached sample small JSON.

Code:

```
var AppData: SectionList?

let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let response = try decoder.decode(SectionList.self, from: pickResult)
self.AppData = response
```

TableView:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return AppData?.items?.count ?? 0
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell()
        let dic = AppData?.items?[indexPath.row].actionType

        return cell 
    }
```

Model:

```
struct SectionList : Codable {

let title : String?
var items : [Item]?
var modified: Bool? = false
}


struct Item : Codable {

    let actionType : Int?
    let actionUrl : String?
    let bgColor : String?
    let booleanValue : Bool?
    var textField : String?
    var textValue : String?
    let unitId : Int? 
    let latitude : Double?
    let longitude : Double?
    let actionParamData: String?
    let actionTitle: String?
    let pickList: [SectionList]?
    var selection: [Item]?
    let multiSelect: Bool?
    let selectedValue: [String]?
    let version: Int?
    let masterId: Int?
    let actionId: Int?
    let itemValue: String?
    var required: Bool? = false
}
```

Sample JSON:

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "actionType": 101,
      "version": 3,
      "pickList": [
        {
          "title": "Sayaç yeri seçimi",
          "items": [
            {
              "textField": "Sayaç Yeri Seçiniz",
              "itemValue": "0"
            },
            {
              "textField": "Sayaç daire girişinde",
              "itemValue": "1"
            },
            {
              "textField": "Sayaç apt. girişinde",
              "itemValue": "2"
            },
            {
              "textField": "Sayaç bodrumda",
              "itemValue": "3"
            },
            {
              "textField": "Sayaç çatı katında",
              "itemValue": "4"
            },
            {
              "textField": "Sayaç bahçede (Müstakil)",
              "itemValue": "5"
            },
            {
              "textField": "Sayaç bina dışında",
              "itemValue": "6"
            },
            {
              "textField": "Sayaç balkonda",
              "itemValue": "7"
            },
            {
              "textField": "Sayaç daire içinde",
              "itemValue": "8"
            },
            {
              "textField": "Sayaç istasyon içinde",
              "itemValue": "9"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "actionType": 1015,
      "version": 3,
      "pickList": [
        {
          "title": "AĞAÇ KURUTMA ÜNİTESİ",
          "items": [

          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "actionType": 1016,
      "version": 3,
      "pickList": [
        {
          "title": "ASTAR FIRINI",
          "items": [

          ]
        }
      ]
    }
]
}
```

**Updated Code**

```
var AppData: [Inner]?

let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let response = try decoder.decode(Root.self, from: pickResult)
let res = response.items.filter { $0.actionType == 103 }
self.AppData = res


func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return AppData?.count ?? 0
    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return AppData?[section].pickList[section].title
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return AppData?.count ?? 0
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell()
    let dic = AppData?[indexPath.section].pickList[indexPath.row].items
    print(dic)

    let data = dic?[indexPath.row].textField
    cell.textLabel?.text = data

    return cell 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need

```
struct Root: Codable {
    let items: [Inner]
}

struct Inner: Codable {
    let actionType, version: Int
    let pickList: [PickList]
}

struct PickList: Codable {
    let title: String
    let items: [PickListItem]
}
struct PickListItem: Codable {
    let textField, itemValue: String
}
```

---

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let response = try decoder.decode(Root.self, from: pickResult)
let res = response.items.filter { $0.actionType = 101 }
```

Comment: Thank you but the problem is I cannot change model structure because its the same structure I am using for other models as well. İs that possible ? However all fields in item models are `optionals` but may be in future it will come

Comment: you don't have to change names you have to change hierarchy for data to be decoded

Comment: Ok let me implement that and how can I show tableView `section` ? at the moment my `var AppData: SectionList?` now it will change to `var AppData: Root? ` am I right?

Comment: I have implemented according to your mentioned answer and changed hierarchy but getting only one `section` and one `row`.  Can you please check my updated question new code added? How I get all sections and rows? I know I am doing something wrong